# Shrink view controller while presenting another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to modely present a view controller, and during the animation I want to shrink the presenting view controller. I saw a lot of apps doing this effect, its seams that the entire view controller including the navigation bar is shrieked.

I'm not sure how to approach this, and I will really appreciate any help about how to make this kind of effect.

here is an example from the mail app, you can see that when the compose view controller is presented, the other view controller is shrieked behind him:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this was for iPad I would tell you to simply use an embed segue, or resize your modal container's superview, but since it is for iPhone that makes things trickier. Apple has said that modal presentation for iPhones is always supposed to be the whole screen, so I doubt they did theirs modally. They either made a custom segue type (I'm not sure how to go about doing that), or they simply are using a view and presenting that on the bottom portion of the screen, with a view inside of it to represent the navigation controller. 
You can add a different viewController's view to the current view controller then call parentVC addChildViewController: and use it like that. Just use a toolbar instead of a nav bar and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do the same and I found [this answer by Brian Sachetta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29040354/1801237) that explains how to accomplish it. The link posted in the answer didn't work for me but I found the sample he is talking about [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LookInside/)